# How to combine 2 strings from an array without repeats in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, what's an elegant way to combine 2 strings from an array without repeating them?
Example:

```
array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

And I want my output to be:

```
['onetwo', 'onethree', 'onefour', 'twothree', 'twofour', 'threefour']
```

Seems simple enough but I've been pretty stumped!

Edit: this is for doing something with anagrams so order does not matter.  ('onetwo' ends up being equivalent to 'twoone'.)

Comment: Question is not clear. What decides that `'onetwo'` is to be included but not `'twoone'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Arrary#combination](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-combination), [Enumerable#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [Array#join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-join) for that.

**Code**

```
array.combination(2).map(&:join)
  #=> ["onetwo", "onethree", "onefour", "twothree", "twofour", "threefour"]
```

**Explanation**

```
array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

a = array.combination(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["one", "two", "three", "four"]:combination(2)>
```

To view the contents of the enumerator:

```
a.to_a
  #=> [["one", "two"  ], ["one", "three"], ["one"  , "four"],
  #    ["two", "three"], ["two", "four" ], ["three", "four"]]
```

Then

```
a.map(&:join)
```

which has the same effect as:

```
a.map { |e| e.join }
  #=> ["onetwo", "onethree", "onefour", "twothree", "twofour", "threefour"]
```

If you wanted `"twoone"` as well as `"onetwo"`, use [Array#permutation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-permutation) instead of `combination`:

```
array.permutation(2).map(&:join)
  #=> ["onetwo"  , "onethree", "onefour"  , "twoone" , "twothree", "twofour",
  #    "threeone", "threetwo", "threefour", "fourone", "fourtwo" , "fourthree"]
```